# How to prevent Laravel from caching files?

Tags: php, caching, laravel-5.7

I am developing a laravel app. I am sending a verification email with the help of inbuilt function `Email verification`. I had setup **mailtrap** credentials and successfully receiving emails in my Mailtrap inbox.

But When I changed these credentials to my **sendgrid** credentials the Laravel is still sending the email to my mailtrap inbox looks like the .env has been **cached**.

The same happens to my `AppServiceProvider` file I had made some changes to my email subject but I am still getting the older version of that email.

I have tried clearing cache using

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
```

But still, nothing changed Laravel still loading a previous version of files.

I want to load the newer version each time I made any changes to `.env` or `AppServiceProvider`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi After clearing cache run

> php artisan clear-compiled
>
> php artisan optimize

Comment: I had tried these but it doesn't work @TechGenzHosting .

Comment: i think the better way is to re-run composer and then user php artisan vendor:publish

Comment: What do you mean by re-running composer?

Comment: run composer update --no-scripts and then php artisan vendor:publish

Comment: Now what to publish there are many options after running `php artisan vendor:publish`?

Comment: you can publish all or the specific package that related to Mailtrap also use cntrl + shift + r to refersh page to avoid browser cache

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem isnt Laravel itself try this:
Open php.ini

```
opcache.revalidate_freq=0
opcache.fast_shutdown=0
```

Change this lines and restart apache.

Comment: first of all there nothing like `opcache.fast_shutdown=0` in `php.in` and changing the `opcache.revalidate_freq=0` doesn't work for me. Any other solution?